# Landscape and portrait android app

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation

I have created two folders layout and layout-land with two xml files, one for portrait and the other for landscape. Both of the xmls work but here is the problem.

My first screen is a login screen and my second screen is a main screen. If I login in portrait and then turn my phone landscape at the main screen. The layout will landscape turn but it uses the portrait xml for the main screen.

The same error occurs if I start in landscape and try to move to portrait later on.

It seems like whatever layout I do for my main then that's the layout that will be used for the rest of the app. Is there anyway to go around this?

Also. I'm already using android:configChanges="orientation" in my manifest for the activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `android:configChanges="orientation"`, then you can override `onConfigurationChanged` to inflate the new layout after a configuration change.

```
@Override
protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);                
    setContentView(...);
}
```

Make sure you have a good reason for preventing the Activity from being recreated on an orientation change... and most importantly don't just do it because orientation changes are crashing your app. Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications.

Answer (score 2):

Using `android:configChanges="orientation"` means you will be handling the orientation change in code. If you want it to automatically switch layouts, you shouldn't have that there.

Comment: To elaborate:  that `configChanges` value means you are circumventing Android's built-in handling of configuration changes (which is the part that would switch out the xml files for you).  If you remove it, you will need to be aware that your Activity will be killed and recreated on rotation with the xml file for the new orientation.

Comment: Yeah thats the reason why I kept it there because I didn't want it to be killed and recreated. So... I understand that what I"m doing is wrong but am not sure where to go from here

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using `configChanges` in the first place? Why are you using it?

Comment: The only reason I was using it was because I didn't want the app to restart on a changed orientation but i do want the new xml to display with a changed orientation

Comment: Alex's answer should work fine for that, but like he said, it's not recommended in most situations.  It can cause more problems than it solves unless you're careful about it. Handling the restart with `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` is the recommended path.

Comment: I'll take a stab at the onSaveInstanceState() and restore. I've also gotten that suggestion from a coworker. Thanks for the help

Comment: I've looked into onSaveInstanceState and such but I dont see how this is going to help change my xml file to the correct one. All I get from those two methods is that it will save the data I have entered so I will use them but how will that change my xml's?

Comment: When you remove the `android:configChanges="orientation"` line, it will automatically switch xml's for you when you flip the phone. You use the InstanceState methods to save your entered data, so that when it kills/restarts your activity, you'll be able to recreate the current state from the data you saved. You don't have to worry about switching the xml's, you just have to recreate the state before the activity restarted.

Comment: if i take out that line and write the the code for save and restore, it still restarts my app when there's an orientation change and brings me back to the first screen.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both xml files present in two different folders have same name.